# Button Clicking feature using LWP:Useragent module in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a requirement where I got to send sms to the mobiles when the systems are down. I have LWP:Useragent module through which I would like to to send values to the fields and click submit button. Using post method I can post values to the fields in the of the webpage where we can send free sms. But how do we click the submit button and go to the next page and type message to send once you have login to the account(The process is login to your account and then send sms using websites like way2sms.com). Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Regards,
Preethy

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you:

1) Check API of SMS service, it's more easy to through it.

2) If you know details of POST/GET request
- send POST/GET request to log in on site
- save cookie
- send POST/GET request with SMS notification

3) If you want to make process of fill and then clicking submit button (see it module: [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) )